# PayPal Checkout - Double Privacy Policy & Terms

Tags: checkout, paypal, terms-and-conditions

When I want to checkout with Paypal there are double Privacy Policy & Terms.
I only need 2 but they´re 4.

See here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/oq1ppr3tzekf3iy/tset.jpg?dl=0

Without Paypal everything ist right. Where can I edit this Site?

Comment: Nobody can help?

Answer (score 1):

Easy solution:
in Magento backend go to 
-> Sales
-> Terms and Conditions

Link the existing documents to the appropriate language.
In my case: link two documents to German, two documents to English.